# iterator in python that should print 10 valid id numbers

Tags: python

Below is my code so far,The code should implement an iterator that prints 10 valid  IDs as at the condition at check_id function .

https://www.codepile.net/pile/b1PVdbBq

The output should be:
123456782
123456790
123456808
123456816
123456824
123456832
123456840
123456857
123456865
123456873
but  somehow the my output is  wrong...help...

```
import string
letters = string.ascii_letters
digits = string.digits


class NumNotNineLong(Exception):

    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def __str__(self):
        return "The number you provided is not nine digits long."

class NotNumber(Exception):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __str__(self):
        return "The input you provided is not an integer"

class IDIterator():

    increment = 1

    def __init__(self,_id):
        self._id = _id  

    def __iter__(self):
       return self 

    def __next__(self):

        while check_id_valid(str(self._id)[-9::]) == False:
            self._id *= 2
            self._id += IDIterator.increment
            IDIterator.increment += 1
        if check_id_valid(str(self._id)[-9::]):
            result = str(self._id)[-9::]
            self._id *= 2
            self._id += 1
            IDIterator.increment = 2
            return result



def check_id_valid(id_number): #A function that checks whether ID number are valid or not
    for letter in str(id_number):
        if letter not in string.digits:
            raise NotNumber
    numbers = [int(i) for i in str(id_number)]
    if len(numbers) != 9:
        raise NumNotNineLong
    set_numbers = []
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            set_numbers.append(numbers[i])
        else:
            set_numbers.append(numbers[i] * 2)
    true_numbers = []
    for num in set_numbers:
        if num > 9:
            temp = [int(i) for i in str(num)]
            true_numbers.append(sum(temp))
        else:
            true_numbers.append(num)
    if sum(true_numbers) % 10 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def main():
    result = IDIterator(123456780)
    for _ in range(10):
        print(result.__next__())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The exercise goes like this: a boolean function called check_id_valid that is defined as:
def check_id_valid (id_number):
The function obtains as an ID number (integer) parameter and returns a true boolean value (True), otherwise returns a false value (False).
It works great when the check_id function is self-contained

Then a class should be implemented to represent an iterator named IDIterator.

This class has an attribute named id_ that represents an ID number in the range of 0 to 999999999 (this attribute is initialized when creating an iterator instance).

The **iter** method that returns the iterator instance must be used in the above class.

The **next** method that returns the next valid ID number in the range between id_ (inclusive) and 999999999 must be used in the above class.

To check that the code you have written is working, write a master program with an iterator from the class you created.

The iterator with the next ID value must be initialized 123456780, generate 10 new IDs and print them to the screen. Here is the output you should receive:

Comment: What's wrong in it it does print 10 values,
Do you want iterator stops if 10 values are done printing ?

Comment: These are the exercise requirements, to initialize iterator  the 9-digit

Comment: the  iteretor  should  print  these id numbers 
123456782
123456790
123456808
123456816
123456824
123456832
123456840
123456857
123456865
123456873

Comment: What is the logic behind `__next__` and `check_id_valid`? what are you trying to do there?

Comment: I wrote down ... The exercise is the implementation of an iterator that will print 10 ID numbers...and The __next__ method returns the next valid ID number each time in the range between id_ (inclusive) and 999999999.

Comment: You misunderstood me, there are a lot of calculations there and changing the id (including doubling it several times, why do expect it to be bigger by 2 or 10?). Please explain what's behind those actions? why do you expect this output?

Comment: I expect this output because that's how the exercise requirements, to reach this output,

Comment: The exercise goes like this: A class representing an iterator named IDIterator must be exercised.
This class has an attribute named id_ that represents an ID number in the range of 0 to 999999999 (this attribute is initialized when creating an iterator instance).

The __iter__ method that returns the iterator instance must be used in the above class.
The __next__ certificate must be used in the aforementioned department, which returns the following valid ID number each time
The iterator with the next ID value must be initialized 123456780, generate 10 new IDs and print them to the screen.

Comment: no  one  can  help   with  this ?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand what you wanted to do here:

```py
def __next__(self):

    while check_id_valid(str(self._id)[-9::]) == False:
        self._id *= 2
        self._id += IDIterator.increment
        IDIterator.increment += 1
    if check_id_valid(str(self._id)[-9::]):
        result = str(self._id)[-9::]
        self._id *= 2
        self._id += 1
        IDIterator.increment = 2
        return result
```

Here is code in the way you tried to do it (but I do not recommend using it, because that's not what they asked for!):

```py
class IDIterator:

    def __init__(self, _id):
        self._id = _id
        self.ok = ""

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        x = self.ok
        while not check_id_valid(str(self._id)[-9:]):
            self._id += 1
        else:
            self.ok = self._id
            self._id += 1
            return x
```

I recommend you to use the code below:

```py
class IDIterator:

    def __init__(self, _id=0, range=999999999):
        self._id = _id
        self.range = range
        self.count = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        while self.count < self.range:
            x = self._id
            if not check_id_valid(x):
                self._id += 1
            else:
                self._id += 1
                self.count += 1
                return x
        else:
            raise StopIteration
```